Android Talkback, need help figuring out how to ignore the helper text for textinputlayout
I'm trying to write a custom AccessibilityDelagate for a TextInputLayout; this contains a TextInputEditText that has a helper text labeled as "required indicating that it is going to be a required field tied to the enabling of a button. Visually, looks fine, but attempting to ignore it for talkback, I'm not sure how. A solution from Copilot led to me attempt to find field called "helperTextView" in class TextInputLayout, but I get thrown back a NoSuchFieldException.
fun TextInputLayout.makeHelperTextNonAccessible() {
    try {
        val helperTextViewField = TextInputLayout::class.java.getDeclaredField("helperTextView")
        helperTextViewField.isAccessible = true
        val helperTextView = helperTextViewField.get(this) as? View
        helperTextView?.importantForAccessibility = View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field helperTextView in class Lcom/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout

It proving to be troublesome as well when talkback reads out the full custom content description set to the textinputlayout whenever focus is swiped to the required field.
The end goal desired is to have the required field TextInputLayout function and read out my custom contentdescription saying that is a required field, while at the same time, disabling accessibility for the helpertext and ignoring it while swiping.
